# How do I specify what column/feature I want to predict in a RNN?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, tensorflow2.0, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to use a time-series data set with 30 different features and I want to predict the future values for 3 of those features. Is there any way I can specify what features I want to be used for output and how many outputs using TensorFlow and Sckit-learn? Or is that just done when I am creating the x_train, y_train, etc. sets? I want to predict the heat index, temperature, and humidity based on various meteorological factors (air pressure, HDD, CDD, pollution, etc.) The 3 factors I wish to predict are part of the 30 total features.

I am using TensorFlows RNN tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series

```
univariate_past_history = 30
univariate_future_target = 0

x_train_uni, y_train_uni = univariate_data(uni_data, 0, 1930,
                                           univariate_past_history,
                                           univariate_future_target)
x_val_uni, y_val_uni = univariate_data(uni_data, 1930, None,
                                       univariate_past_history,
                                       univariate_future_target)
```

My data is given daily so I wanted to predict the next day using the last 30 days for example here.

and this is my implementation of the training of the model:

```
    BATCH_SIZE = 256
    BUFFER_SIZE = 10000
    
    train_univariate = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train_uni, y_train_uni))
    train_univariate = 
    
    train_univariate.cache().shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE).repeat()
    
    val_univariate = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_val_uni, y_val_uni))
    val_univariate = val_univariate.batch(BATCH_SIZE).repeat()
    
    simple_lstm_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.LSTM(8, input_shape=x_train_uni.shape[-2:]),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
    ])
    
    simple_lstm_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mae')
    
    for x, y in val_univariate.take(1):
        print(simple_lstm_model.predict(x).shape)
        
    EVALUATION_INTERVAL = 200
    EPOCHS = 30
    
    simple_lstm_model.fit(train_univariate, epochs=EPOCHS,
                          steps_per_epoch=EVALUATION_INTERVAL,
                          validation_data=val_univariate, validation_steps=50)
```

EDIT: I understand that to increase the number of outputs I have to increase the Dense(1) value, want to understand how to specify which features to output/predict

Comment: nah I don't have the data past the end of June. Essentially, I want to predict those three features for the next month given the "expected" conditions for the next month

Comment: So you have (n*30) features of last n days and you want to predict 3 features of (n+1)th day ?

Comment: Yes, and when you say (n*30) features for last n days, you mean 30 values for each of the last n days, right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the model.fit call the variables you want to learn from in a shape compatible with an LSTM layer

So for example, without any code a model like yours might take as input:

[batchsize, n_timestamps, n_features]

and output:

[batchsize, n_timestamps, m_features]

where n is input and m output.

So then you need to give the model the truth data of the same shape as the model output in order for the model to calculate a loss.

So the model.fit call should be:

model.fit(x_train, y_train, ....) where y_train are the truth vectors of the same shape as the model output.

You have to design a model architecture that fits your needs and matches the outputs you expect. I made a toy example, but I have never really worked with this type of NN so no idea if it makes sense for the problem.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, InputLayer, Reshape

ni_feats = 10
no_feats = 3
ndays = 30

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    InputLayer((ndays, ni_feats)),
    LSTM(10),
    Dense(int(no_feats * ndays)),
    Reshape((ndays, no_feats))
    ])
```